# Merging changes head branch to master branch in git

Tags: eclipse, git

I am currently making a project in eclipse.I made changes in **head branch** and as well as in **master branch**.I want to merge those changes and push them to **remote repository**.Please tell me the correct steps so i **merge** both branches and push the changes to **remote repository** without getting **non fast forward warning**.

Answer (score 0):

> I am currently making a project in eclipse.I made changes in head branch and as well as 
>   in master branch.

Normally when people refer to "head" they are talking about `HEAD`, which is not actually a branch but a reference to the "tip" of the currently checked out branch. So if you

```
git clone foo
cd foo
git checkout bar
```

assuming `bar` is a branch, then `HEAD` would refer to the "tip" or last commit of the `bar` branch.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a non fast forward warning on a push, changes have been made to the remote repository.  You to bring those changes into your local branch before you can push.

This is because git requires merge conflicts be resolved in the local repository, not the (usually shared) remote repository.  To bring those changes to your local repository you will need to execute a pair of commands; `git fetch ...` and `git merge ...` results in a merge commit, which some prefer -- while `git fetch ...` and `git rebase ...` if merging the changes without a merge commit is preferred.  Note that `git pull ...` is the same as `git fetch ...` and `git merge ...` and `git pull --rebase ...` is the same as `git fetch ...` and `git rebase ...`.

Which ever way your prefer, once you get the changes to your local repository (and resolve any conflicts there may be) you will be ready to push.